# Proving property of recursive function

Tags: lean

Trying to prove that a sum of positive numbers is positive.

```
-- some function
variable {w : nat -> int}

-- sum of w's from 0 to i
def sw : nat -> int
| 0     := w 0
| (i+1) := sw i + w (i+1)

-- w is always positive
axiom w_pos : ∀ i : nat, 0 < w i

-- sum of w's is always positive
lemma sw_pos : ∀ i : nat, 0 < sw i // error here
| 0     := w_pos 0
| (i+1) :=
have h₁ : 0 + w (i+1) < sw (i+1), from add_lt_add_right (sw_pos i) (w (i+1)),
have h₂ : 0 < 0 + w (i+1), from add_lt_add_left (w_pos (i+1)) 0,
show 0 < sw (i+1), from lt_trans h₂
```

On the declaration of `sw_pos`, Lean complains that it "don't know how to synthesize placeholder context" for `sw`.

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Lean cannot infer the variable `w` when applying `sw`. Why did you make it implicit?

Comment: Lean gives a different error if you remove the `{}`. Do you mean pass `w` by hand to all `def`s? That will be ugly when other set function joins `w`.